# How do I display images from a field in a View as grid?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that displays images from an image field of a specific node and I want to display those images in a grid but Views groups them together so the whole node is put into the grid cell instead of each image separately.

How can I make such View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit image field in view and uncheck "**Display all values in the same row**" checkbox under "**MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS**" fieldset. This will tell view to render each image in node as single row. See screenshot below for field settings:

[image]

Comment: I did that as a first thing but it didn't work.

Comment: In this case, can you try clearing cache and see if its working. Also try if its working for other users including admin.

Comment: I was uid1 and I was looking at it in the preview.

Comment: I have repeated the steps and it turned out that the preview was not showing the proper result. So I trusted you were right, saved it, wen' to the page and it was working as supposed to,thanks.

Comment: Yes, sometimes views preview doesn't show proper output, so its always good to confirm the output on actual page.